# ASP.NET Core 6.0 using React,js can't host a dynamic file

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a `WebPreviewController` in my ASP.NET Core application, but I'm facing an issue when I navigate to the `/WebPreview/DynamicCoverPreview` endpoint with query parameters. The problem is that I am redirected to the default index page, even though the `POST` method works fine.

Here's the `WebPreviewController` code:

```cs
[Route("webpreview")]
[Controller]
public class WebPreviewController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // this can be hit
        return new JsonResult("{\"screw\": 'you'}");
    }

    [HttpGet("DynamicCoverPreview")]
    public IActionResult GetCoverPreview([FromQuery] int TemplateID, [FromQuery] string Body, [FromQuery] string Company, [FromQuery] string Title)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

        try
        {
            var template = Templates.TemplateManager.GetTemplateByID(TemplateID);
            var t = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(template.HtmlPath);
            var reps = UserInfoData.UserManager.GetUser().GetReplacements();
            reps.Add("company", Company);
            reps.Add("jobtitle", Title);
            reps.Add("recipient", "Hiring Manager");
            reps.Add("body", Body);

            foreach (var key in reps.Keys)
            {
                t = t.Replace(key, reps[key]);
            }

            return File(t, "text/html");
        }
        catch
        {
            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body><h1>Template Not Found (404)</h1></body></html>"), "text/html");
        }
    }
}
```

I've also confirmed that the spaproxy has the controller mapped to /webpreview:

```
const context = [
  "/weatherforecast",
  "/userinfo",
  "/chatgpt",
  "/promptgeneration",
  "/webpreview"
];
```

I can get a response from the Post action but when I navigate to

```
/WebPreview/DynamicCoverPreview?TemplateID=0&Body=undefined&Company=name&Title=jobtitle
```

I am sent to the default index page.

Tried messing with the program.cs file, tried asking chatgpt and bard, tried by removing the query string requirements. nothing.

Comment: Please try input the uri in address bar ,check if it could hit the endpoint,if yes,share the detailed codes  how you nevigate to an other url,if no ,share the codes in your program.cs

Comment: Putting the the uri with the endpoint in the address bar does not work,
Program.cs:
```var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this to **Program.cs**:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "WebPreview",
        pattern: "WebPreview/{action=DynamicCoverPreview}",
        defaults: new { controller = "WebPreview" }
    );
});
```

and changed the url to lowercase:`/webpreview/dynamiccoverpreview?TemplateID=0&Body=undefined&Company=Jabil&Title=IT Repair Technician`